# How to compute the Q matrix

Tags: python, opencv

I want to compute the depth map and the point cloud using opencv and for this purpose i need the Q matrix. I can't use the `stereoRectify` because the angle between the cameras is too high.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

To compute the depth map and point cloud from stereo images, you will need to first compute the disparity map between the two images. This can be done using a stereo matching algorithm, such as block matching or semi-global block matching.

Once you have the disparity map, you can then use it to compute the depth map and point cloud. To do this, you will need to know the intrinsic parameters of the cameras (focal length and principal point) as well as the extrinsic parameters (relative orientation and position) of the cameras.

The Q matrix is a 4x4 matrix that contains these intrinsic and extrinsic parameters, and is used to convert the disparities in the disparity map to depths in the depth map. The Q matrix can be computed using the function cv2.stereoRectify, which requires the intrinsic parameters of the cameras, the extrinsic parameters of the cameras, and the size of the images.

If you are unable to use cv2.stereoRectify because the angle between the cameras is too high, you will need to compute the Q matrix manually. To do this, you will need to know the intrinsic parameters of the cameras, the extrinsic parameters of the cameras, and the baseline (distance between the cameras). You can then use this information to build the Q matrix according to the following formula:

```
Q = [1 0 0 -cx;
0 1 0 -cy;
0 0 0 f;
0 0 -1/baseline]
```

Where cx and cy are the principal points of the cameras, f is the focal length, and baseline is the distance between the cameras.

Once you have computed the Q matrix, you can use it to convert the disparities in the disparity map to depths in the depth map using the following formula:

```
depth = Q[3][2] / disparity
```

You can then use the depths to generate the point cloud by using the intrinsic parameters of the cameras to project the points back into 3D space.

Comment: Can i describe the baseline like this? Baseline b  is `b= b2 - b1` where `b2 = R2^T . t2` and `b1 = R1^T . t1`